# Conditional type argument in C#

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument

I would like to deserialize object into a given class type, depending on whether the ajax response was successful or not.

So I written the following method:

```
public IAjaxResponse GetResponse<TOk, TFail>()
{
    var responseJson = this.response as Dictionary<string, object>;

    object obj = null;

    if ((string)responseJson["status"] == "ok")
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOk>(responseJson);
    else
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TFail>(responseJson);

    return (IAjaxResponse)obj;
}
```

Now it's pretty straightforward to use:

```
var response = GetResponse<ClassWhenOk, ClassWhenFail>();
if (response is ClassWhenFail responseFail) {
    Error.Show(responseFail.message);
    return;
}
[..]
```

---

**Now my problem is**: sometimes, there are generic responses which happend to be always 'ok' status so I don't want to use the second type argument for failed status.

So I would want to use something like that:

```
               \/ notice one type argument
GetResponse<ClassWhenOk>();
```

This is not allowed though since using this generic method requires 2 type arguments.

**So here comes my question**:

Can I somehow mark the second type argument (`TFail`) as 'not required'? Or should I rather go for different approach?

Comment: how about passing a `null` value?

Comment: 2 functions seems like the appropriate way forward here.

Comment: If I where in your shoes, I create a SuperClass with status field and wrap hole object into a class

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I don't think that would change anything, I couldn't have the 'conditional' type argument there either.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Yeah, I was just wondering because I wanted to skip the code repeatability. If nothing would help I will try your solution.

Comment: I think you're over-concerned about code duplication here! We're talking about a few lines of code in 2 functions with the same name. It should not be too hard to maintain even if you duplicate and keep the functions close by each other in the source code (with comments!). Be pragmatic. Solve the trivial "problem" and move on to the interesting stuff that adds value to your application.

Comment: Seems like the behavior is different (am not sure what you plan to do in the event of an unexpected error if `TFail` isn't passed), so you probably should have two functions anyway.

Comment: @JohnWu Yep, that would be another problem to solve. Since I thought it's somehow possible to make it null by default, I was relying on the checks in such area. Anyways, I will go for the two method approach :-)

Comment: @LoztInSpace Well, sometimes it seems like I try too hard :p... and ending in a black hole. Not much knowledge about C# though so I think it was reasonable to ask a question.

Comment: The simple answer I could think of is, use single class to pass the result with status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just doesn't make sense. The `responseJson` object cannot be a `Dictionary<string, string>` and a `string` at the same time. It would be good to be able to post real code for us to work from.

Here's a refactored example that does compile, but needs some work to behave properly at run-time. Nevertheless, all you need is an alternative overload to make this work.

```
public IAjaxResponse GetResponse<TOk, TFail>(string response)
{
    var responseJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    object obj = null;

    if ((string)responseJson["status"] == "ok")
        obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOk>(response);
    else
        obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TFail>(response);

    return (IAjaxResponse)obj;
}

public IAjaxResponse GetResponse<TOk>(string response)
{
    return (IAjaxResponse)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOk>(response);
}
```

The second method could even be this:

```
public IAjaxResponse GetResponse<TOk>(string response)
{
    return GetResponse<TOk, FailDontCare>(response);
}
```

That just avoids code duplication.

Comment: As propsed in the comments, this is the solution I went. +1. I posted this question due to lack of knowledge about C# (still learning). I thought that there is some magic trick that could help (C# has lots of them ;)).